# Cannot Get Menu item to Template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-3.0

i have 2 apps in Django Project one is Saas and seccond one is Menu.
from Saas i can get everything to template but from Menu i cannot get menu items in html navbar.
my project Tree is

[image: Picture For Tree]

Code in Html Template

```
                {% for item in Menu_list %}
                <li class="nav-item dropdown dropdown__megamenu">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-opener" href="#">
                       {{ item.title }}
                    </a>

                    <div class="custom-dropdown-menu custom-megamenu">
                        <div class="content">
                            <ul class="megamenu">
                                <a href="#">menu</a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
```

Code for Views.Py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from .models import Menu,MenuItem
    def index(request):
        Menu_list = Menu.objects.all()
        MenuItem_list = MenuItem.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'header-footer.html',{'Menu_list' : Menu_list,
                                          'MenuItem_list': MenuItem_list,}
                                          )
```

this is my models in admin panel everything works fine and i cant add menu and sub menu item just cannot get it from database.or in django can i geT fro database without views?

```
My models

from django.db import models


 class Menu(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(
    (u'Name'),
    max_length=100
    )

slug = models.SlugField(
    (u'Slug')
    )

base_url = models.CharField(
    (u'Base URL'),
    max_length=100,
    blank=True,
    null=True
    )

description = models.TextField(
    (u'Description'),
    blank=True,
    null=True
    )

class Meta:
    verbose_name = (u'menu')
    verbose_name_plural = (u'menus')

def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s" % self.name

def __str__(self):
    return self.__unicode__()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Re-order all items from 10 upwards, at intervals of 10.
    This makes it easy to insert new items in the middle of
    existing items without having to manually shuffle
    them all around.
    """
    super(Menu, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    current = 10
    for item in MenuItem.objects.filter(menu=self).order_by('order'):
        item.order = current
        item.save()
        current += 10


class MenuItem(models.Model):
menu = models.ForeignKey(
    Menu,
    verbose_name=(u'Name'),
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

order = models.IntegerField(
    (u'Order'),
    default=500
    )

link_url = models.CharField(
    (u'Link URL'),
    max_length=100,
    help_text=(u'URL or URI to the content, eg /about/ or http://test.com/')
    )

title = models.CharField(
    (u'Title'),
    max_length=100
    )

login_required = models.BooleanField(
    (u'Login required'),
    blank=True,
    default=False,
    help_text=(u'Should this item only be shown to authenticated users?')
    )

anonymous_only = models.BooleanField(
    (u'Anonymous only'),
    blank=True,
    default=False,
    help_text=(u'Should this item only be shown to non-logged-in users?')
    )

class Meta:
    verbose_name = (u'menu item')
    verbose_name_plural = (u'menu items')

def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s %s. %s" % (self.menu.slug, self.order, self.title)
```

Comment: Can you post your models? You will probably need to add an additional `{% for subitem in item.menuitem_set.all %}` to loop through the sub menu items

Comment: i upload models sair

Answer (score 0):

You can list all `MenuItem` using [the reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

```
{% for item in menu_list %}
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            {{ item.title }}
        </a>
        <ul>
            {% for subitem in item.menuitem_set.all %}
                <li>
                    <a href="">
                        {{ subitem.title }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Bear in mind this will introduce a new query for every menu you have, so you should [use `prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) in your `QuerySet`. You should also use [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in your models to make the reverse relationship more readable:

```py
class MenuItem(models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, related_name="items", ...)
```

```py
def index(request):
   menu_list = Menu.objects.prefetch_related("items").all()
   return render(request, 'header-footer.html',{'menu_list' : menu_list})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are derived `Menu_list` using `Menu.objects.all()`. And in `menu` model there are no any type of `title` field which are you want to use in template as `item.title`. So, it will give you nothing because there are no any type pf 'title'
field in `Menu` list.